# Rails: how to i18n an array of strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm having trouble using `I18n.translate` to translate an array.

Specifically, I've got this array,

```
module TaskEnums
  OCTAVE_BANDS = [:hz63, :hz125, :hz250, :hz500, :hz1000, :hz2000, :hz4000, :hz8000, :hz16000]
end
```

and I have the following translation in a YAML file.

```
en:
  TaskEnums:
    OCTAVE_BANDS:
        hz63: "63 Hz"
        hz125: "125 Hz"
        hz250: "250 Hz"
        hz500: "500 Hz"
        hz1000: "1000 Hz"
        hz2000: "2000 Hz"
        hz4000: "4000 Hz"
        hz8000: "8000 Hz"
        hz16000: "16000 Hz"
```

In my view, I'd like to display a dropdown menu that allows users to select a frequency.

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :frequency, TaskEnums::OCTAVE_BANDS %>
<% end %>
```

I know I can translate individual symbols with `t :symbol`, but this approach doesn't seem to work with arrays (e.g. `t TaskEnums::OCTAVE_BANDS` doesn't do what I need).

Does anyone know how I can translate the `OCTAVE_BANDS` array, so that the translations appear in the dropdown?  This seems like it must be a common problem, so I assume (and hope!) that there's a simple solution... can anyone suggest how to get it done?

Many thanks,

D.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `scope` option for your `I18n.t` call:

```
t TaskEnums::OCTAVE_BANDS, scope: 'TaskEnums.OCTAVE_BANDS'
# => ["63 Hz", "125 Hz", "250 Hz", "500 Hz", "1000 Hz", "2000 Hz", "4000 Hz", "8000 Hz", "16000 Hz"]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! For the record, I found that I needed to include parentheses to make this work in the view, e.g. `t(TaskEnums::OCTAVE_BANDS, scope: 'TaskEnums.OCTAVE_BANDS')`, but I guess that's obvious to more experienced Rubyists.  Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

jdoe's answer worked for me! I used this on a form input field.

```
f.input :state, as: :radio, collection: t(Model.states.map(&:name), scope: 'attributes.states')
```